# Setting a laravel storage directory permission by ebextentions

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions, laravel-artisan

I'm working on elastic beanstalk exextentions. A storage-permission-denied error occurs every deployments and I a have to type command to resolve that. Does the code below(.extensions/chmod.config), prevent the error occur ?

```
container_commands:
  01addpermission:
    command: "chmod -R 755 /var/app/current/storage"
  01clearcache:
    command: "php /var/app/current config:cache"
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin. You saved my time. A postdeploy platform hook worked this case.

Comment: (.ebextensions/chmod.config)   container_commands:
      01addpermission:
        command: "chmod +x .platform/hooks/postdeploy/artisan.sh"

Comment: (.platform/hooks/postdeploy/artisan.sh) #!/bin/bash
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage
php /var/www/html/artisan config:cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code sadly will not work. The reason is that [container commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) run when your app is in the `staging` folder, **not** in `current` folder:

> The specified commands run as the root user, and are processed in alphabetical order by name. Container commands are **run from the staging directory**, where your source code is extracted prior to being deployed to the application server.

You can try to use **relative paths**:

```
container_commands:
  01addpermission:
    command: "chmod -R 755 ./storage"
  02clearcache:
    command: "php . config:cache"
```

The **alternative** is to use [postdeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) platform hook which runs commands after you app is deployed:

> Files here **run after** the Elastic Beanstalk platform engine **deploys the application** and proxy server